# How can I have ActiveRecord map additional values from the intermediary table that results from includes to those included models?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

When using ActiveRecord's `includes` method with eager-loading, the resulting SQL is an intermediary table consisting of columns selected from the parent class' table and any tables that were specified in the include.  For example:

```
Subject.includes(:topics).references(:topics)
# OR
Subject.eager_load(:topics)
```

will generate a single query which results in a single table with columns from both the `subjects` as well as the `topics` tables.  ActiveRecord then distributes these columns between the relevant models so that one can access the attributes on the models without having to do another query, for instance:

```
subjects = Subject.includes(:topics).references(:topics)
subjects.first.title
subjects.first.topics.first.description # no additional query performed
```

Now, I would like to do a custom select with an aggregate calculation, and have that be made available to the Topic model instance.  For example, I can do this:

```
subjects = Subject.includes(:topics).references(:topics).select('COUNT(subject.id) AS total_subjects')
subjects.first.total_subjects # outputs total number of subjects
```

but I would also like to do this:

```
subjects = Subject.includes(:topics).references(:topics).select('COUNT(subject.id) AS total_subjects', 'COUNT(topics.id) AS total_topics')
subjects.first.topics.first.total_topics # outputs total number of topics
```

however, ActiveRecord only maps custom select results to the model instances of the class that invoked the query (in this case, Subject instances).

Is there a way to get ActiveRecord to map values to branch/leaf nodes?

Comment: This is going to be extremely difficult as ActiveRecord dynamically assigns those `t1_c0`  style aliases to the columns and any solution would require digging into the internals and will be very likely to break. I also think it maps the aliases to attributes by looking at the tables columns so it may not work at all for columns that are not defined in the schema.

Comment: Have you considered other options like adding a counter cache?

Comment: Thanks @max, I looked at the source code and came to a similar conclusion than you did, so I added a column on the "topics" table with the same name as one of the aliased attributes I was trying to assign but ActiveRecord didn't automatically map the column to that attribute.

I looked into counter cache, it is an option, but requires a lot more moving parts. I was hoping to just make this query once, cache it, and have my entire tree structure at the ready whenever I need it. (my actual query is of course much more complicated with many more levels than the example)

Comment: A materialized view maybe? https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/rules-materializedviews.html

Comment: Thanks, I believe a subquery should basically give me the correct results, but getting ActiveRecord to realise which model to apply the aliased attribute to is going to be the main problem.